# iOS, Implementing text reading and highlighting selected text with pre saved MP3 files

Tags: ios, objective-c, text, highlighting, audio

Im developing an application that have a `text` saved in an `array`, and mp3 files that's in the project.

i wanna to play the mp3 file with the text that been `touched` and highlight the `text` or change its `background color`.

my problem is with knowing the position of the text in the screen and connect touching that text with the play event and highlighting this text

im wondering if there is a sample code for this or a project somewhere.

Please Advice.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how complex your text layout need to be you could try a variety of options.

If your text layout doesn't need to be complicated you could just try put the text in a button and set the background colour of the label in the button when the user touches it.

Otherwise you might need some combination of webviews and js to accomplish what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

`NSAattributedString` delegate `Methods` to do that:

```
- (void)removeAttribute:(NSString *)name range:(NSRange)range;
- (void)addAttribute:(NSString *)name value:(id)value range:(NSRange)range;
```

and for your consideration it's available for iOS6.